# How many passports can I have?

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, uk-citizenship, multiple-citizenship

By birth, I am a Bangladeshi citizen and have a valid passport. I also have Italian citizenship and thus also carry an Italian passport. I have been living in the UK for a certain time, and I want to be a British citizen as well. How many valid passports can I carry at a time? [There is already a question on how many citizenship one can hold.](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5945/what-is-the-highest-number-of-citizenships-one-can-hold/5948#5948)

Comment: There does not seem to be any blanket rule limiting the number of citizenships. You do need to check each one's rules. For example, does a Bangladesh dual nationality certificate permit multiple other citizenships, or only one? Or can you have multiple certificates.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between passports and citizenship! It is possible, by the internal laws of several countries of the world, to hold a passport of that country and **NOT** be a citizen. Further, while countries may have their own restrictions regarding their own citizens also being citizens of other countries, those restrictions may not apply to other designations that may qualify for a foreign passport (such as 'national', royal subject, honorary, etc...).

Comment: There are two questions here. The answer to the 'passports' questions is different from the answer to the 'citizenship' question. And the OP is been quite specific in the difference.

Comment: Voted to reopen (and edit).

Comment: For someone who travels a lot, it's moderately easy to get a 2nd UK passport (eg so you can send one off for a visa while still travelling). I believe some other countries also do the same. Would you count Italian + UK + 2nd UK passport as being 2 or 3?

Comment: @Gagravarr, Yeah, yet another reason why the passports questions is a unique one from the citizenship question. You can get temporary passports, diplomatic passports, and Lord only knows what else.

Comment: @ouflak Given how vague / "it depends" the citizenship one is, then add in the variation of how many passports you can get from a given country, this question seems un-answerable to me

Comment: @Gagravarr, Well that is obviously the answer. In fact that was going to be my answer: Given all of the various rules specific to each country on whom to and why they might issue a passport, there is no limit. It might raise some eyebrows at a ticket counter or border patrol if you whip out a half dozen and tell them take their pick, but there is no known limit to how many passports one can carry.